# Remove images from a specific domain from string with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm not very good with regex so I'm hoping to get a bit of help with this one. Basically I need to remove images that are inserted from a specific domain in a string. The string could contain images from other domains, that need to remain, and text that needs to stay too.

I have tried using regex like so (fairly sure I'm still way off though):

```
$content = preg_replace("/http://www.theblacklisteddomain.com[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content);
```

I'm open to other solutions outside of regex that don't involve loading a library. It needs to happen on the server side, I know that with jQuery or vanilla JS this would be a lot easier.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to replace the url or the full html `<img />` tag ?

Comment: The full image tag including the src. Basically strip out any images inserted from a domain. The exact URL from the domain can vary based on the path of the image.

Comment: Edited, but it's not a [good way parsing html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` chars like this :

```
 $content = preg_replace('/<img.*src="http:\/\/www.theblacklisteddomain.com(.*?)".*\/?>/', ' ', $content);
```

See the [ideone example](http://ideone.com/SeOaXL).

By the way it's not a [good way parsing html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php).

Comment: Thank you! I just realised there was a better way to solve the problem in my situation. Basically it was a 1px x 1px image getting inserted. So the solution is to just check the size of the image. Thanks for your help!